# How to add more `?` automatically in java in accordance with whatever amount of columns will be placed in the interface

Tags: java, api, crud

I'm trying to create an api so I can use it to whatever project I need to create. I'm still new to java so I'm sorry in advance for the wrong codes. Anyways, I've got here this code that has the CRUD statements (except for Read/Retrieve).

```
import java.sql.*;

public class KitApiNew {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement PSInsert = null;
        PreparedStatement PSUpdate = null;
        PreparedStatement PSDelete = null;
        PreparedStatement PSStatement = null;

        String DBTable = "fruits";
        String DBColumnSet = "fruit";
        String DBID = "23";
        String DBColumnSingle = "fruit";
        String DBChoice ="insert";
        String DBCS = "";

        String insertTable = "INSERT INTO " + DBTable + "(" +DBColumnSet+ ")" + "VALUES" + "(?)";
        String updateTable = "UPDATE " + DBTable + " SET " + DBColumnSingle + " = ?" + " WHERE id = ?";
        String deleteTable = "DELETE FROM " + DBTable + " WHERE id = ?";
        String statementTable = "INSERT INTO fruits(fruit) VALUES('grapes')";

        try{

            dbConnection  = getDBConnection();
            dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

        if(DBChoice.equals("insert")){
        //for insert
             PSInsert = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTable);
             PSInsert.setString(1, "Orange");
             PSInsert.executeUpdate();
             dbConnection.commit();
        }

        if(DBChoice.equals("update")){
        //for update
             PSUpdate = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateTable);
             PSUpdate.setString(1, "Apple");
             PSUpdate.setString(2, DBID);
             PSUpdate.executeUpdate();
             dbConnection.commit();
        }

        if(DBChoice.equals("delete")){
        //for delete
             PSDelete = dbConnection.prepareStatement(deleteTable);
             PSDelete.setString(1, DBID);
             PSDelete.executeUpdate();
             dbConnection.commit();
        }

        if(DBChoice.equals("statement")){
             //for statement 
             PSStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(statementTable);
             PSStatement.executeUpdate();
             dbConnection.commit();
        }

            System.out.println("Success!");         

        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Error occured " + e.toString());
            dbConnection.rollback();
        }
        finally{
            if(PSInsert !=null){
                PSInsert.close();
            }
            if(PSUpdate != null){
                PSUpdate.close();
            }
            if(dbConnection != null){
                dbConnection.close();
            }
        }
     }

    private static Connection getDBConnection(){
        Connection con = null;

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Error 1 : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        try{
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bongbong","root","");
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Error 2 : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

## Oh by the way,

The values of the variables are currently temporary. I'll be changing them later to whatever they're going to be catching. I'm referring to these:

```
    String DBTable = "fruits";
    String DBColumnSet = "fruit";
    String DBID = "23";
    String DBColumnSingle = "fruit";
    String DBChoice ="insert";
    String DBCS = "";
```

and this

```
String statementTable = "INSERT INTO fruits(fruit) VALUES('grapes')";
```

## Problem

What I really need help from is with the `?` thing from the first code I posted after the `VALUES` word inside the `String insertTable`. I want it so that when I place a column amount in my interface then it'll add more `?` in accordance with what was inputted (I also want it to add another `PSInsert.setString(n, "value")` with n+1 in accordance with the column amount inputted if it's possible). Can anyone tell me how to? I'm really new to java and I'm still a student studying at his best.

I want it to add those `?` thing because what if I add more columns or if I use another table with more columns other than my `fruits` table. (I want it so that whatever I'm going to place in `DBColumnSet` --with columns separated by comma --will also relate to how many `?` are going to be placed).

Oh by the way, it's a general api so I can't provide an interface.

Comment: Side issue, this will cause problems: `if(DBChoice=="delete"){` Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: Ah yes, I'll be changing it ASAP. I just forgot about it. Thank you @HovercraftFullOfEels